# Creating DateTime parameter in Crystal Reports

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, sqldatatypes

I'm using HDAuthority -database (Help Desk Authority) with Crystal Reports. There's a table named IS_RECEIVED_DATETIME and it's Data Format is Float. The date appears in this kind of format: "20120 112 060 710,00" (2012/01/12 06:07:10). Now because it's in float format, I cannot use it if I want to create parameters in Crystal Reports where Range of DateTime is asked. How can I convert data type Float to a DateTime. I have tried to change the data type with SQL Server 2008 to a DateTime but it always gives me an error "Unable to modify table.   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime"... I don't have enough knowledge for this kind of problem, Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do conversions in crystal reports formulas, take the field in crystal reports formula, change it to a string or text, save it in a variable inside formula, make sure not to display it.

take three substrings of the original date you converted.

not display those substrings in a date format.

let me know if you still have problem, thanks